# How to tell Gitversion to increment versions on every merge on dev?

Tags: git, azure-devops, cicd, gitversion

We create our features on `feature/*` branches and we make Pull Requests on Azure DevOps to merge them on `dev` branch.

On the PR, we have a template that suggest to choose between Fix, Minor or Major.
Selecting one of the options will trigger the corresponding commit (`+semver: (major|minor|patch)`) in the build validation pipeline as we are using GitVersion.

The template in the PR:

```markdown
## Type of update 
    - [ ] Fix
    - [ ] Feature
    - [ ] Major Change
```

The build validation pipeline

```yaml
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

## Job to calculate semantic version
jobs:
  - job: CalculateVersion
    displayName: Semantic versioning

    steps:
      # Checkout with persist credentials
      - checkout: self
        fetchDepth: 0
        persistCredentials: true

      # Install GitVersion
      - task: gitversion/setup@0
        displayName: Install GitVersion
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '5.x'

      # Retrieve Pull Request Description
      - task: PullRequestDescription@0
        name: RetrievePullRequestDescription
        displayName: Retrieve Pull Request description
        inputs:
          action: 'view'
          outputVariable: 'PullRequest.DescriptionContent'
          isOutput: true
          stripIdentifiers: false

      # Add git commit message that will be picked up by GitVersion ("+semver: patch/minor/major")
      # Depending on the Pull Request description, where the developer has marked the type of change
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: Add git commit message for SemVer
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            Write-Host "Configuring git author info.." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            git config user.email "Azure DevOps pipeline"
            git config user.name "Azure.Devops@pipeline.com"
            Write-Host "Doing git checkout..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            git checkout -b $("$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)".replace('refs/heads/', ''))
            Write-Host "Checking Pull Request description..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            $PRdesc = "$(RetrievePullRequestDescription.PullRequest.DescriptionContent)"
            if ($PRdesc -match '(\[x\] \bFix\b)') {
              Write-Host "Adding git (empty) commit message to mark this branch as a 'patch' SemVer increment." -ForegroundColor Cyan
              git commit -a -m "+semver: patch [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty
            } elseif ($PRdesc -match '(\[x\] \bFeature\b)') {
              Write-Host "Adding git (empty) commit message to mark this branch as a 'minor' SemVer increment." -ForegroundColor Cyan
              git commit -a -m "+semver: minor [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty
            } elseif ($PRdesc -match '(\[x\] \bMajor Change\b)') {
              Write-Host "Adding git (empty) commit message to mark this branch as a 'major' SemVer increment." -ForegroundColor Cyan
              git commit -a -m "+semver: major [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty
            } else {
              Write-Host "##vso[task.LogIssue type=error;]Please select the type of change in the Pull Request description, and Re-queue the validation." -ForegroundColor Cyan
              $PRdesc
              exit 1
            }
            Write-Host "Doing git push.." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            git push -f --set-upstream origin $("$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)".replace('refs/heads/', ''))
            Write-Host "Done." -ForegroundColor Cyan

      # Determine the semantic version
      - task: gitversion/execute@0
        displayName: Determine SemVer
        inputs:
          useConfigFile: True
          configFilePath: ".azuredevops/gitversion.yml"
          updateAssemblyInfo: true
```

Gitversion.yml file used by the powershell task in the validation pipeline:

```yaml
next-version: 1.0
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatchTag
assembly-informational-format: '{InformationalVersion}'
mode: ContinuousDeployment
increment: Inherit
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ci
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
legacy-semver-padding: 4
build-metadata-padding: 4
commits-since-version-source-padding: 4
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
commit-date-format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
# ignore:
#   sha: []
#   commits-before: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
merge-message-formats: {}
branches:
  main:
    regex: ^main$
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  feature:
    regex: ^feature?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: false
  hotfix:
    regex: ^hotfix(es)?[/-]|^bugfix(es)?[/-]|^fix?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: patch
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  develop:
    regex: ^dev$
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
    pre-release-weight: 1000
```

**Question**: Currently, every merge of `feature/*` into `dev` branch will increment (minor, major or patch, according to the checked box in the Pull Request's description) based on the last version of `main`. How can we make it increment based on the last version made on the `dev` branch instead ?

Expected flow:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Actual flow:
[image]

Comment: I haven't use the tool you're using, but it feels weird to use empty commits to determine the version. Tags or baking in versions to the file is more typical. Is semver actually reading the current version from those empty commits, or is it perhaps using the last tag?

Comment: @TTT GitVersion goes off of tags to determine the next version number. The commit message can contain some metadata that controls which segment of the version is incremented, but that's more typically included in something like, say, a PR merge commit message to bump a major version upon breaking changes.

Comment: @DanielMann great, that makes sense. I can't tell what OP's issue is, but I wonder if no tags are being generated at all, since the arrows point to what looks like a second tag with the same name on a different commit, which isn't possible.

Comment: It seems that you are using the gitversion tool https://gitversion.net/docs/learn/how-it-works. Is it working as your expectation with local git tool command?

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT I didn't try it locally, only remotely with the Azure DevOps extensions. If I have time, I will give it a try locally.